# Facebook web hooks for page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an account on FB and I then created a page on FB as admin of the page.

I then setup Facebook web hook Page subscriptions. Here are the details:

[Web hook details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj9DL.jpg)

I checked every single item including "feed" which are important in this case.

Now I signed in to FB using another user/account and posted a post on the Facebook page. However my webhook endpoint is not getting hit. I can confirm that it is not getting hit.

Is there anything else that I have to do to enable web hook page subcriptions? I read the documentation and everything seems very tangled.

Please let me know.

Comment: facing the same issue here.Did you come up with something?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the solution to this problem is to add the accounts you want to access the webhooks as testers, developers, or admins on your app configuration page.  Go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{YOUR_APP_ID}/roles/` and click Add Administrators, Add Developers, or Add Testers .

Answer (score 0):

Once you've set up the Webhook
Until your app is approved by Facebook only **testers**, **developers**, or **admins** can see it and use it. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security#sandbox)

As soon as you're happy with how your app behaves, you should follow [Facebook's App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) guide to submit your app for approval.
Then only you can use it for **public** use.